# std::stringstream; move assignment does not leave source in invalid state

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

According to the documentation, the move assignment operator should leave a source string stream in an invalid state:

> Moves the string stream. The source stream becomes of invalid state after the operation.

(From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/operator%3D)

Given that, I would expect the following to output `0`, but instead it outputs `1`, using GCC 6.3.1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream source;
    std::stringstream target;
    target = std::move(source);
    std::cout << bool(source);
    return 0;
}
```

I assume the documentation should read that the state is undefined instead of invalid, which seems a bit too strong in the context of streams. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: “invalid” here presumably doesn’t refer to its `iostate` flag (“failure” ≠ “`failbit`”). But it’s an unfortunate wording.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I sort of expected the wording to be the problem here as well. So then there is no way to detect that `source` in this case has been moved from?

Comment: Is this a [`XY`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When you move A into B, it does a shallow copy of A and nullifies B so B shouldn't be used anymore. This is usually done with a swap of the values in A and B OR shallow copy all the underlying data of A into B then nullify all the values in B (or let B destroy itself by going out of scope). Technically, you shouldn't be using B after it has been moved (at least that's what I've been taught -- because you don't know its state or what it contains).

Comment: Cppreference updated